# CANFI compatabilty with the rtl-sdr R820T

Tags: noise, sdr

Is CANFI compatible only with the devices mentioned in documentation? It means that there is no opportunity for it to establish connection with rtl-sdr R820T?

Comment: The [FAQ](http://www.canfi.eu/index.php/faq) says: "From V2.7 the more common R820Txx is also supported using a special version of rtlsdr.dll."

Comment: Unfourtunately, I didn't find any special .dll file. Should I modify it myself somehow?